# How would I query based on the subraction of a date and another column as hours

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, rails-activerecord

I have these models - `Sport`, and `Match`. A `Sport` `has_many :matches` while a `Match` `belongs_to :sport`.

`Sport` has a field `hours_before_inactive`, which is the hours after a match starts that it is considered inactive in the system, while match knows when it starts via a field `:starts_at`

How would I query for all active matches at any time? Either active record or straight sql(Mysql) is ok. Preferably 1 query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For starters ditch the hours_before_inactive

It should be calculated on the fly based on date math functions against now()

Comment: I think u are missunderstanding its purpose, think of it as the average length of matches for this sport..

Comment: Maybe more detail then. I will reread but a stub of something would help. So i could grasp what i am missing. But from what i read it sounds like u want to save data based on current now() then use that and it would be stale versus date math

Comment: Ok i get it hours_before_inactive is like an integer or dec ie 3.5 that assumes when the match is over based on a fuzzy guess. So to be conservative a baseball game should be over in 4 hours "normal" worst case but some games have gone 27 innings 12 hours. So i get the concept but question the accuracy

Comment: accuracy isnt the problem at this point, just curious how I would implement this.. At this point I just hardcoded it as 2, but would initial idea is it is sport specific.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you:

```
Match.includes(:sport).where("starts_at BETWEEN Now() AND  NOW() + INTERVAL sports. hours_before_inactive HOUR")
```

Just be sure with time zones of both mysql and your rails server

Comment: Have you tried this? I tried making the Interval dynamic this way but it errored out

Comment: what error it gives? Actually i have used somewhat similar to this in my model

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
Match.where('starts_at BETWEEN '#{time}' AND DATE_ADD('#{time}, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)')
```

Comment: So my question is how to make that `2` dynamic, as defined by another column in a parent model